# Looking for general feedback on Python OOP banking project

Tags: python, object-oriented

I am in the process of trying to teach myself Python, and am at a point where I feel some general feedback on my styling/code efficiency would be super useful in order for me to progress.

I have created a simple banking system in order to practice OOP (which I am still finding a little confusing).

Would anyone be able to offer advice on any simple Python mistakes I am making or rules I am breaking? For example - would it be better to pass through certain parameters with the methods, eg

`def create_account (self, name, deposit): ....`

Could someone also shed some light as to whether an Abstract Base Class is needed with this code (another concept I am struggling a little to understand)?

Thanks in advance!

```
from random import randint

class Bank ():

    def __init__ (self):
        self.savingsAccount = {}

    def create_account(self):

        self.name = input("Please input your full name: ")
        while True:
            try:
                self.deposit = int(input("Please input the amount of your initial deposit: "))
            except:
                print("Please input a valid integer amount. ")
            else:
                print ("You have deposited £{}".format(self.deposit))
                break
        self.accountno = ''.join(["{}".format(randint(0, 9)) for num in range(0, 5)])
        print ("Your account number is {}.".format(self.accountno))
        self.savingsAccount[self.name] = [self.accountno, self.deposit]



    def access_account(self):

        while True:
            self.name = input("Please input your full name: ")
            if self.name in self.savingsAccount.keys():
                while True:
                    self.accountno = input("Please enter your account number: ")
                    if self.accountno == self.savingsAccount[self.name][0]:
                        break
                    else:
                        print ("There is no such account number associated with this name.")
                break
            else:
                print ("We cannot find this name in our system.")



    def display_balance (self):

        print ("You currently have £{} in your account.".format(self.savingsAccount[self.name][1]))


    def withdraw_money (self):

        while True:
            try:
                withdraw = int(input("How much money would you like to withdraw?")) 
            except ValueError:
                print ("This value must be an integer.")
            else:
                if withdraw <= self.savingsAccount[self.name][1]:
                    print ("You have successfully withdrawn £{}.".format(withdraw))
                    self.savingsAccount[self.name][1] -= withdraw
                    self.display_balance()
                    break
                else: 
                    print ("Sorry, you do not have enough money in your account.")


    def deposit_money (self):

        while True:
            try:
                deposit = int(input("How much money would you like to deposit?")) 
            except ValueError:
                print ("This value must be an integer.")
            else:
                print ("You have successfully deposited £{}.".format(deposit))
                self.savingsAccount[self.name][1] += deposit
                self.display_balance()
                break    



def user_choice1():  

    while True:
        choice1 = input("Enter 1 to create an account.\nEnter 2 to access an existing account.\nEnter 3 to exit.\n")
        if choice1 not in ["1", "2", "3"]:
            print ("Please enter 1, 2 or 3..")
        else:
            break
    return choice1


def user_choice2():

    while True:
        choice2 = input("Enter 1 to display balance.\nEnter 2 to withdraw money.\nEnter 3 to deposit money.\nEnter 4 to return to the main menu.\n")
        if choice2 not in ["1", "2", "3", "4"]:
            print ("Please enter 1, 2, 3 or 4.")
        else:
            break

    return choice2 



def previous_page ():

    while True:
        return input("Would you like to return to the previous page? Enter yes or no:")[0].lower() == 'y'






print ("Welcome to the bank!")   
bank=Bank()
while True:
    userchoice1 = user_choice1()
    if userchoice1 == "1":
        bank.create_account()
        if not previous_page():
            break
        else:
            continue
    elif userchoice1 == "2": 
        bank.access_account()     
        while True:
            userchoice2 = user_choice2()
            if userchoice2 == "1":
                bank.display_balance()
                if not previous_page():
                    break
                else:
                    continue 
            elif userchoice2=="2":   
                bank.withdraw_money()   
                if not previous_page():
                    break
                else:
                    continue 
            elif userchoice2=="3":
                bank.deposit_money()
                if not previous_page():
                    break
                else:
                    continue
            elif userchoice2=="4":
                break
    else:
        break

print ("Thankyou for using the bank!")
```

Comment: (1) An abstract base class makes sense if you at least can imagine one or more siblings of Bank which all have some behavior or properties in common. (2) You should not number functions, use names like e. g. "user_choice_main" and "user_choice_account" instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Removing Duplication

There are several places in your program where you repeat the same logic for prompting the user to enter an `int`, and then ask them to retry if they type something invalid, this is a good opportunity to create a general function to handle that:

```
def read_int(prompt_msg, error_msg):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(prompt_msg))
        except ValueError:
            print(error_msg)
```

Which you could use in several places to eliminate the `while True` / `try` / `except` / `break` logic which occurs in several places, for example to simplify the `deposit_money` method:

```
def deposit_money (self):
    deposit = read_int("How much money would you like to deposit?", "This value must be an integer.")
```

Even without the duplication of this logic, splitting the code to read an `int` and retry away into a separate function significantly reduces the complexity of the `deposit_money` method and makes the intent clearer

#### Separation of Concerns

Your `withdraw_money` method changes the balance available combines together the code for re-asking the user if they try to go overdrawn as well as changing the account balance - ideally a function should "do one thing, and do it well", so there's an opportunity to split the check-and-re-ask code into another function.   For example:

```
def read_withdraw_amount(self):
    while True:
        withdraw = read_int("How much money would you like to withdraw?", "This value must be an integer.")
        if withdraw > self.balance:
            print("Sorry, you do not have enough money in your account.")
        else:
            return withdraw

def withdraw_money(self):
    withdraw = self.read_withdraw_amount()
    print("You have successfully withdrawn £{}.".format(withdraw))
    self.balance -= withdraw
    self.display_balance()
```

#### Object Oriented Programming

> I have created a simple banking system in order to practice OOP (which I am still finding a little confusing).

It's not at all un-common to find OOP confusing as it's a subjective art at the best of times; I would try to approach it with the mindset of keeping the two core principles in-mind of **High Cohesion** and **Loose Coupling**, which to summarise in plain English is roughly this:

- **High Cohesion** is about grouping together functions/methods and state/data which are conceptually very closely related to each other - for example, your `deposit` and `withdraw` methods are both very closely related to the concept of the balance of a single bank account since they both affect the balance of one account at a time.
- **Loose Coupling** is about minimising the extent to which functions/methods and classes need to depend upon each other.  For example, your `Bank` class contains a list of all accounts, yet the `deposit` and `withdraw` methods only affect a single account at any one time, so conceptually there's no need for those methods to have any link to a class which manages a whole list of accounts.

> Could someone also shed some light as to whether an Abstract Base Class is needed with this code (another concept I am struggling a little to understand)?

Inheritance and Abstract Base Classes are among many different possible ways of allowing code reuse - so a typical reason to use it would be having multiple classes which would otherwise require copies of similar or the same methods/behaviour; an abstract base class might be a suitable tool for sharing/reusing that code between those classes,

However, code reuse in this way should only happen where there's a very strong conceptual "identity" link between those classes. Inheritance implies tight coupling, so the relationship between a *derived* class and a *base* class should be that the derived class is a **specialisation** of that base class (i.e. the code in a derived class specialises or extends whatever exists in the base class).

There are no hard-and-fast rules about whether or not to use inheritance, since it really all links back to whatever problem/concept/real-world-thing you're trying to model using classes in the first place.

However, base classes aren't *needed* in any kind of strict sense; there are often better ways of writing Object-Oriented code without using inheritance or base classes at all. Inheritance implies *tight coupling* between a derived class and a base class, so it's something which should be used with caution, and often avoided.

There are other ways to reuse code, including Composition, which tends to provide looser coupling, and still provides all the same opportunities for code reuse.  Composition allows a class to hold a reference to an object of another class without being so tightly-coupled to it.

#### Introducing a SavingsAccount class

One way which you could improve the Coupling and Cohesion of your program could be to introduce a `SavingsAccount` class which is *decoupled* from the Bank class, responsible for all methods whose purpose is only to access or modify a single `SavingsAccount` at any one time.

For example:

```
class SavingsAccount:
    def __init__(self, balance):
        # the Account Number and Balance are now named class variables
        self.account_no = ''.join(["{}".format(randint(0, 9)) for num in range(0, 5)])
        self.balance = balance

    def print_account_no(self):
        print("Your account number is {}.".format(self.account_no))

    def display_balance (self):
        print("You currently have £{} in your account.".format(self.balance))

    def read_withdraw_amount(self):
        while True:
            withdraw = read_int("How much money would you like to withdraw?", "This value must be an integer.")
            if withdraw > self.balance:
                print("Sorry, you do not have enough money in your account.")
            else:
                return withdraw

    def withdraw_money(self):
        withdraw = self.read_withdraw_amount()
        print("You have successfully withdrawn £{}.".format(withdraw))
        self.balance -= withdraw
        self.display_balance()

    def deposit_money (self):
        deposit = read_int("How much money would you like to deposit?", "This value must be an integer.")
        print("You have successfully deposited £{}.".format(deposit))
        self.balance += deposit
        self.display_balance()
```

Just a note on the `__init__` method:

```
def __init__(self, balance):
    self.account_no = ''.join(["{}".format(randint(0, 9)) for num in range(0, 5)])
    self.balance = balance
```

When a `SavingsAccount` object is created, this method will run, so the code which creates the object will need to provide the initial balance. like this:

```
# Create a SavingsAccount object with £100 starting balance
account = SavingsAccount(100)
```

There's a few benefits here:

- the `account_no` and `balance` for a `SavingsAccount` have a strong name which makes their intent much more obvious.   Previously those were "magic" numbers of `[1]` and `[0]`, so it had readability issues in needing the person reading the code to realise/remember the difference between 0 and 1
- Provides clean logical separation between the `Bank` and the `SavingsAccount` - the `SavingsAccount` class has no connections to the `Bank` at all, it's entirely self-contained.
- Methods such as `deposit_money` and `withdraw_money` are less "noisy" since they no longer need to pluck the account from a list belonging to the `Bank`.

With that in mind, the `Bank` class gets a whole lot smaller, and is no longer concerned with code whose responsibility is around the state of individual accounts in the list.  The Bank knows how to create a new account, and how to provide access to an existing account:

```
class Bank:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.savingsAccount: Dict[str, SavingsAccount] = {}

    def create_account(self):
        name = input("Please input your full name: ")
        deposit = read_int("Please input the amount of your initial deposit: ", "Please input a valid integer amount. ")
        print("You have deposited £{}".format(deposit))
        account = SavingsAccount(deposit)
        self.savingsAccount[name] = account
        account.print_account_no()

    def access_account(self):
        while True:
            name = input("Please input your full name: ")
            if name in self.savingsAccount.keys():
                account = self.savingsAccount[name]
                while True:
                    account_no = input("Please enter your account number: ")
                    if account.account_no == account_no:
                        break
                    else:
                        print("There is no such account number associated with this name.")
                break
            else:
                print("We cannot find this name in our system.")
        return account
```

The relationship between `Bank` and `SavingsAccount` is one of *Composition* -- i.e. the `Bank` owns zero-or-more `SavingsAccount` objects.

Note that any code which needs to access or modify the fields (variables) within a `SavingsAccount` object, such as printing the account number, is now part of that `SavingsAccount` class too.

Since the account-specific methods are no longer part of `Bank`, the code which needs to work with those methods will need a `SavingsAccount` object, so the `access_account` method can return the `SavingsAccount` object from the list.

Back to possible uses of inheritance: Perhaps if you decided to extend the program in future, there might be different variations on the `SavingsAccount` which the bank could own - e.g.  maybe you would create a `PensionAccount` class which disallows someone from withdrawing any money since it's a deposit-only account -- in that case, it could indeed make sense to treat the `SavingsAccount` as a base class and inherit the `PensionAccount` from it then override the `withdraw` method.

The menu code further down which handles Account-specific concerns such as letting the user display/deposit/withdraw are only concerned with a `SavingsAccount` object, which leads onto the next item:

#### Menu

- There's a lot of duplication involving `previous_page()`, `break`, and `continue` which could be eliminated by re-structuring the logic slightly.
- There's no need for separate `userchoice1` and `userchoice2` variables - one variable is enough.
- The names of the `user_choice1()` and `user_choice2()` functions aren't very descriptive - try to use verbs with function names.   The functions are for menu options related to either the Bank or the Account, so something like `do_bank_menu()` and `do_account_menu()` would be more insightful for someone reading the code.
- The account portion of the menu, now only concerned with accounts and not banks, would need a `SavingsAccount` object, which it can get from the `Bank` object:

  ```
  elif user_choice == "2":
      account = bank.access_account()
      while True:
          user_choice = do_account_menu()
          if user_choice == "1":
              account.display_balance()
          elif user_choice == "2":
              account.withdraw_money()
          elif user_choice == "3":
              account.deposit_money()
          elif user_choice == "4":
              break
          else:
              continue

          if not previous_page():
              break
  ```

#### Menu as a class

Classes aren't just for combining methods and data - classes are often good tools for grouping methods together without any data - all of the menu functions could be grouped together inside a `Menu` class.      This allows the menu itself to be treated as a self-contained unit, and helps create further logical separation between different areas of your program.

#### Main

It's generally recommended to use a `main()` function in Python for some of the reasons explained here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041238/why-use-def-main

#### Putting it Together

Here's a code listing with those structural changes - https://repl.it/repls/FlawedJuniorShareware

```
from typing import Dict
from random import randint


def read_int(prompt_msg, error_msg):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(prompt_msg))
        except ValueError:
            print(error_msg)


class SavingsAccount:
    def __init__(self, balance):
        self.account_no = ''.join(["{}".format(randint(0, 9)) for num in range(0, 5)])
        self.balance = balance

    def print_account_no(self):
        print("Your account number is {}.".format(self.account_no))

    def display_balance (self):
        print("You currently have £{} in your account.".format(self.balance))

    def read_withdraw_amount(self):
        while True:
            withdraw = read_int("How much money would you like to withdraw?", "This value must be an integer.")
            if withdraw > self.balance:
                print("Sorry, you do not have enough money in your account.")
            else:
                return withdraw

    def withdraw_money(self):
        withdraw = self.read_withdraw_amount()
        print("You have successfully withdrawn £{}.".format(withdraw))
        self.balance -= withdraw
        self.display_balance()

    def deposit_money (self):
        deposit = read_int("How much money would you like to deposit?", "This value must be an integer.")
        print("You have successfully deposited £{}.".format(deposit))
        self.balance += deposit
        self.display_balance()


class Bank:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.savingsAccount: Dict[str, SavingsAccount] = {}

    def create_account(self):
        name = input("Please input your full name: ")
        deposit = read_int("Please input the amount of your initial deposit: ", "Please input a valid integer amount. ")
        print("You have deposited £{}".format(deposit))
        account = SavingsAccount(deposit)
        self.savingsAccount[name] = account
        account.print_account_no()

    def access_account(self):
        while True:
            name = input("Please input your full name: ")
            if name in self.savingsAccount.keys():
                account = self.savingsAccount[name]
                while True:
                    account_no = input("Please enter your account number: ")
                    if account.account_no == account_no:
                        break
                    else:
                        print("There is no such account number associated with this name.")
                break
            else:
                print("We cannot find this name in our system.")
        return account


class BankMenu:
    def __init__(self, bank: Bank):
        self.bank = bank

    def do_bank_menu(self):
        while True:
            choice = input("Enter 1 to create an account.\n"
                           "Enter 2 to access an existing account.\n"
                           "Enter 3 to exit.\n")
            if choice not in ["1", "2", "3"]:
                print ("Please enter 1, 2 or 3..")
            else:
                return choice

    def do_account_menu(self):
        while True:
            choice = input("Enter 1 to display balance.\n"
                           "Enter 2 to withdraw money.\n"
                           "Enter 3 to deposit money.\n"
                           "Enter 4 to return to the main menu.\n")
            if choice not in ["1", "2", "3", "4"]:
                print ("Please enter 1, 2, 3 or 4.")
            else:
                break
        return choice

    def previous_page(self):
        while True:
            return input("Would you like to return to the previous page? Enter yes or no:")[0].lower() == 'y'

    def run(self):
        print("Welcome to the bank!")
        while True:
            user_choice = self.do_bank_menu()
            if user_choice == "1":
                self.bank.create_account()
                if not self.previous_page():
                    break
            elif user_choice == "2":
                account = self.bank.access_account()
                while True:
                    user_choice = self.do_account_menu()
                    if user_choice == "1":
                        account.display_balance()
                    elif user_choice == "2":
                        account.withdraw_money()
                    elif user_choice == "3":
                        account.deposit_money()
                    elif user_choice == "4":
                        break
                    else:
                        continue

                    if not self.previous_page():
                        break
            else:
                break


def main():
    print("Welcome to the bank!")
    bank = Bank()
    bank_menu = BankMenu(bank)
    bank_menu.run()
    print("Thankyou for using the bank!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this detailed and informative answer - highly appreciated!